# Mysql query to find facebook friends using app but not the users friend

Tags: php, android, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an android app. I am a bit stuck on one query. When a user logged in through facebook , i want to show him his facebook friends who are not his friends within the application. I have the following mysql tables;

**TABLE user -** 
(columnn)
userid-name-facebookid

**TABLE friend** 
(column)
key_id-userid-username-friendid-friendname-accepted(0/1)
The entry for this table is AB style ( A is friend of B , B is friend of A)

Through my app when a user logs in i get his friends using the app through facebookgraph. And send username and facebookids of his facebook friends using the app. In server side, i make the following query - which does not work -

```
SELECT u1.facebookid,u1.name FROM users u
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT facebookid, name FROM users
    WHERE facebookid IN ($facebookids) 
) u1
ON u1.name = u.name
INNER JOIN friend f
WHERE f.username = '$username' AND f.friendname != u1.name
GROUP by u1.name
```

Comment: Is your test user is the admin user of your app ?

Comment: Actually everthing is fine regarding facebook sdk. I get the facebookids, no problem with that. Just need a hand for the query :)

Comment: Won't this do? select * from friend f1 where accepted=0 and userid=<loggedinuserid>

Comment: @Akshay If not one has sent a friend request the friend table will be empty.